# Sources for 'Android API 11 Platform' not found

Tags: java, android-studio, android-api-levels

I'm trying to compile an android project using Android Studio. 
Originally, it's an Eclipse Project.
I want to import the project from Android Studio; however, I encountered some problems.

In all of the `.class` files, it showed

```
"Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 49.0(Java 5.0)"
"Sources for 'Android API 11 Platform' not found."
```

But, I have already installed Android API 11:

[image: The SDK Manager window]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you compiling with api11 in the 2015?

Comment: Because the project is the old one.  I thought if I installed Android API 11, it would work.   Is there anything what I thought wrong ?

Comment: In any case you can compile with api 23. It is not the minSdk.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti    Thanks for your suggestion.I have changed to the api 23 and it works. Now, it only exists one problem : "Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 49.0(Java 5.0)"    How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you solve that problem? I have the same issue with API 23.